# Can Diver eclipse plugin be used for remote debugging?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, remote-debugging

Diver plugin is used to provide sequence diagrams.
Can it be used with remote debugging which will provide the sequence of execution?

More information can be looked at: [DIVER](http://diver.sourceforge.net/docs/Diver.html)